# Hash value in jsp file client side

Tags: html, jsp, hash

In my dynamic web project I am using this form to submit username and password to my jsp file **loginRequestHandler.jsp** to check later in a Java Class if the data exists.

```
<form action="loginRequestHandler.jsp">
            <table cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Benutzername:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><b>Passwort:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" required/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Anmelden" /></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
```

How can I hash the password client side that the password will be NOT send in a clear view to my server? I will later add SSL, too.

How do I need to save the password in my database that the check will work?

Comment: You'd need to use the same hashing algorithm on both sides--beyond that, it doesn't matter. Of course, if you're hashing on the client side, anybody *else* can hash it in the same way as well, so good luck.

Comment: @DaveNewton so this is not a good way to do it? At the moment I am hashing it on the server and save it to my database.

Comment: Which is how it should be done, and use SSL.